# Is it secure for a company to allow you to display your Wi-Fi password when signed onto their site?

Tags: password-management

My ISP, CableOne, has a feature on their site that (when signed onto your account) allows you to retrieve (display on your screen) your Wi-Fi password if you are using one of their modems (which I am). I feel like this is a security issue. I think my Wi-Fi password should be more protected than my CableOne password.  I would like a more informed opinion.

Comment: it's not the modem, you just need to get a real wifi router. also, i hate to break it to you, but your wifi password's not all the safe, showing on the screen or not...

Comment: Why should your Wi-Fi be better secured than the account? Presumably you have money and PII attached to the account. The account is available to the world, but the Wi-Fi is only available to your neighborhood.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are talking about factory assigned WIFI router WIFI password. 
The default factory WIFI password is meant for the user to connect during initial setup, as well as after hard hardware reset.

You should always change the default WIFI password when you setup the router. After changing the password, the internet reference will be utterly useless unless somebody adjacent to your get the password and able to hard reset your router modem.

Comment: Or the routers phone home with their passwords. Which sounds bad, but not certainly false.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt OP mentioned it is WIFI password key, not router security key.

Comment: I understand that. It is information the router has and could send.

Comment: Ok.  What I get from this:
1. my wifi is not secure anyway so don't worry
2. other ISPs display wifi pw's too, so CableOne is'nt so bad.
3. If i get my own router, CableOne won't be able to display it.
4. My wifi can only be hacked if the hacker drives to my neighborhood. So if he doesn't have a car...
5. It would help if i have a strong password.  I do.
6. wifi is vulnerable to an MiTM attack.  After reading a bit, it seems the MiTM attacks relative to wifi usually occur on public networks?
7. mootmoot thinks I might be using the default password.  I'm not.

Comment: @gingerfaun you should clarify that you provide a new WIFI password, but this password has been synchronized to the ISP database.  Then this is a big security issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not secure. What you are seeing means that the password is not being hashed when stored. That is a security flaw, but to mootmoots point, wifi really is not very secure to begin with.

Comment: what good is a wifi password if it's hashed?

Comment: I would just search password best practices. Its the common stuff you can think of. Long, with mix of special characters and numbers and what not. The weakness inherit in wifi is really in the encryption. But none of that matters when a MiTM attack can capture a handshake